# How to remove file with invalid name (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

By mistake I have createad file with name:

```
0);          if (count($keys->toArray())  0) {              $this->obj->api(messages.send, [                 access_token > $this->group->getAccessToken(),                 user_id > $this->userId,                 message > Я
```

I'm not able to remove it via ssh or sftp.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the file by its inode number.

Every filesystem entry has a number, called the inode number.  With this you can remove a file without referencing the file's name

```
ls -il
```

Will list inode numbers along with the long entry.  For example:

```
> ls -il example
8460278 -rw-r--r-- 1 edwbuck edwbuck 0 Mar 30 21:13 example
```

which can be removed by

```
> find . -inum 8460278 -exec rm -i {} +
```

which will use the find command to locate the file and then pass the difficult to type name (properly escaped) to the `rm` command.  If you don't like the "prompt me if I really want to do it" behavior in `rm` remove the `-i` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SSH connection, you should just be able to delete this using bash auto-complete; tested and working.

```
rm -- 0<tab>
```

Evaluates to the escape sequence:

```
rm -- 0\)\;\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ if\ \(count\(-\>toArray\(\)\)\ \ 0\)\ \{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -\>obj-\>api\(messages.send\,\ \[\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ access_token\ \>\ -\>group-\>getAccessToken\(\)\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ user_id\ \>\ -\>userId\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ message\ \>\ Я
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete it with  rm ./0)  (and tab to complete).